# Rotations in a treap

Tags: trees, heaps, binary-search-trees

I have a treap like the first image and I want to reach the second image to restore min heap order property. I can't understand which kinds of rotations have been done.

Image 1
[image: Image 1]

Image 2
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, node `F` is violating the heap invariant. Its priority is too small, and it needs to be moved up the treap. The only operation needed is a *single rotation*. If you are not already familiar, please read [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation). Here are some illustrative diagrams:

- https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Tree_rotation.png
- https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Tree_rotation_animation_250x250.gif

I've drawn snapshots of the rotation process below. In each diagram, I've marked where the rotation is about to happen with stars (e.g. `*E:14*`). The direction of rotation should be obvious: the goal is to get `F` up the tree! Notice that as long as `F` is violating the heap invariant, we're rotating the parent of `F`.

```
       G:3
      /   \
    B:6   K:8
   /   \     \
A:11   D:9   L:12
      /   \
    C:16  *E:14*
             \
             F:2


       G:3
      /   \
    B:6   K:8
   /   \     \
A:11  *D:9*  L:12
      /   \
    C:16  F:2
          /
        E:14


       G:3
      /   \
   *B:6*  K:8
   /   \     \
A:11   F:2   L:12
      /
    D:9   
   /   \
 C:16  E:14


       *G:3*
       /   \
     F:2    K:8
     /        \
   B:6         L:12
  /   \
A:11   D:9   
      /   \
    C:16  E:14


      F:2
     /   \
   B:6    G:3
  /   \     \
A:11   D:9   K:8 
      /   \    \
    C:16  E:14  L:12
```

There are some really nice properties of rotations which make this work. Obviously rotations preserve the in-order traversal of the tree. But also notice that, whenever a subtree is detached/reattached during a rotation, there is never a priority inversion (i.e. you never attach a subtree as a child of a node with a larger priority).